# How to change values more efficiently

Tags: r

I want to replace the `,` with a `.` as the decimal point in a dataframe. I can do this with `df$X2005 <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', df$X2005))` for each variable. Is there a more efficient way to do this for the whole dataframe at once?

Some example data:

```
df <- structure(list(country = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Chile", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Korea", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "United Kingdom", "United States"), class = "factor"), X2005 = structure(c(26L, 2L, 34L, 33L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("10,3533", "10,4187", "10,8089", "10,8629", "10,882", "11,0173", "15,8399", "5,0226", "5,4488", "5,6273", "5,8713", "6,2137", "6,6397", "6,9339", "7,0448", "7,5719", "7,8534", "7,9457", "8,1819", "8,2668", "8,2883", "8,3556", "8,394", "8,4295", "8,4456", "8,4794", "8,7437", "9,0304", "9,0615", "9,4427", "9,6618", "9,77", "9,8295", "9,9833"), class = "factor"), X2006 = structure(c(25L, 2L, 31L, 34L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("10,0326", "10,2177", "10,3877", "10,6374", "10,7468", "10,9516", "15,9368", "5,0169", "5,6845", "5,8109", "6,1019", "6,2008", "6,285", "6,6937", "7,3477", "7,5148", "7,5836", "7,7495", "8,1986", "8,2586", "8,2807", "8,3448", "8,39", "8,4289", "8,5204", "8,564", "8,8247", "8,8401", "8,948", "9,1292", "9,4811", "9,7487", "9,9243", "9,9621"), class = "factor"), X2007 = structure(c(27L, 3L, 31L, 1L, 14L, 13L), .Label = c("10,0263", "10,2099", "10,2617", "10,4771", "10,7642", "10,8754", "16,1608", "5,1597", "5,7779", "6,0372", "6,3331", "6,3858", "6,5223", "6,5494", "7,1288", "7,6299", "7,6744", "7,7553", "7,8565", "7,9023", "8,043", "8,2295", "8,4769", "8,4908", "8,5014", "8,504", "8,5531", "8,746", "8,9172", "9,0913", "9,5254", "9,8104", "9,9873", "9,9942"), class = "factor"), X2008 = structure(c(26L, 6L, 34L, 4L, 17L, 15L), .Label = c("10,1268", "10,183", "10,2189", "10,2537", "10,289", "10,4896", "10,7042", "10,9909", "11,0232", "16,6201", "5,8474", "6,0577", "6,0745", "6,586", "6,8189", "6,8863", "7,1361", "7,1819", "7,4631", "7,7052", "8,0208", "8,3068", "8,3457",     "8,5513", "8,605", "8,751", "8,8915", "8,9402", "8,9521", "9,0591", "9,1344", "9,2284", "9,3051", "9,9128"), class = "factor"), X2009 = structure(c(24L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 21L, 22L), .Label = c("", "10,0115", "10,0496", "10,1957", "10,5938", "10,8137", "11,0005", "11,1729", "11,3992", "11,4722",     "11,7314", "11,7516", "11,8823", "17,6706", "6,4098", "7,039", "7,1018", "7,2127", "7,6797", "7,7356", "7,8649", "7,9514", "7,9657", "9,0423", "9,152", "9,17", "9,1947", "9,4037", "9,5258", "9,6247", "9,636", "9,6743", "9,9056", "9,939"), class = "factor"), X2010 = structure(c(23L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 18L, 19L), .Label = c("", "10,1995", "10,503", "10,797", "10,8817", "11,0318", "11,0751", "11,3738", "11,5495", "11,677", "12,0661", "17,6911", "6,1782", "6,3394", "7,0229", "7,1675", "7,2911", "7,37", "7,4319", "7,6856", "8,0302", "8,8718", "8,9481", "8,9888", "8,995", "9,2925", "9,312", "9,4079", "9,4224", "9,4688", "9,5277", "9,5504", "9,589", "9,6074"), class = "factor"), X2011 = structure(c(NA, 5L, 4L, 8L, 18L, 17L), .Label = c("", "10,2345", "10,2844", "10,5139", "10,7769", "10,8671", "11,0148", "11,1784", "11,3323", "11,6343", "11,9369", "17,683", "5,922", "6,6464", "6,8709", "7,3692", "7,5011", "7,5206", "7,7333", "7,8877", "7,9416", "8,8501", "8,9042", "9,0019", "9,027", "9,1296", "9,2256", "9,2837", "9,2969", "9,4184", "9,4661"), class = "factor"), X2012 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, 5L, NA), .Label = c("", "11,2132", "11,2955", "7,5249", "7,6077", "7,8226", "8,7596", "8,923", "9,148", "9,167", "9,3722"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("country", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead read your data in the correct format.

If you use [`read.table`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) for instance, change the `dec = ","` parameter. You'll probably need to change the `na.strings = "<NA>"` parameter as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop:

```
for (col in names(df[,-1])) {
  df[,col] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", df[,col]))
}
```

Comment: Although JuliánUrbano pointed to an easier solution with `dec = ","`, this works as wel.